# Jordan Block Transformation ,

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is given that a certain matrix A has eigenvalue 1 repeated thrice, eigenvalue 2 repeated twice, and eigenvalue 3 with no repeats. What are the possible geometric multiplicity for these eigenvalues. Write down the possible Jordan forms of A.

My try : The characteristic equation is (l-1)^3*(l-2)^2*(l-3) . We have to find out the ordinary eigen vectors & corrosponding generalised eigen vectors to check theor geometric multiplicity . Further we will be able to write the possible jordan forms by placing 1's in the super diagonal .

But how to find the A matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a purely combinatorical problem:

From the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t) = (t-1)^3 (t-2)^2 (t-3)$ we know that $A$ is a $(6 \times 6)$-matrix (since $\deg \chi_A = 6)$ and that the diagonal entries of the the Jordan canonical form of $A$ (which as precisely the eigenvalues of $A$) are $\lambda_1 = 1$ thrice, $\lambda_2 = 2$ twice and $\lambda_3 = 3$ once.
Hence the Jordan canonical form of $A$ looks like this:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & * &   &   &   &   \\
      & 1 & * &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 2 & * &   \\
      &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
      &   &   &   &   & 3
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
This gives us (up to permutation of the Jordan blocks) the following $6$ possible Jordan canonical forms:
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &   &   &   &   &   \\
      & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 2 &   &   \\
      &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
      &   &   &   &   & 3
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 2 &   &   \\
      &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
      &   &   &   &   & 3
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 2 &   &   \\
      &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
      &   &   &   &   & 3
  \end{pmatrix},
  \\
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &   &   &   &   &   \\
      & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 2 & 1 &   \\
      &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
      &   &   &   &   & 3
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 2 & 1 &   \\
      &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
      &   &   &   &   & 3
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 &   &   &   &   \\
      & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 2 & 1 &   \\
      &   &   &   & 2 &   \\
      &   &   &   &   & 3
  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{gather*}
The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is the number of Jordan blocks belonging to $\lambda_i$.
So in the above six cases we get the following geometric multiplicities:
$$
\begin{array}{l|ccc}
    {}
  & \lambda_1
  & \lambda_2
  & \lambda_3
  \\
  \hline
    \text{first case}
  & 3
  & 2
  & 1
  \\
    \text{second case}
  & 2
  & 2
  & 1
  \\
    \text{third case}
  & 1
  & 2
  & 1
  \\
    \text{fourth case}
  & 3
  & 1
  & 1
  \\
    \text{fifth case}
  & 2
  & 1
  & 1
  \\
    \text{sixth case}
  & 1
  & 1
  & 1
  \\
\end{array}
$$