# geometric multiplicity problem

Tags: linear-algebra

It is given that a certain matrix A has eigenvalue 1 repeated thrice, eigenvalue 2 repeated twice, and eigenvalue
3 with no repeats. What are the possible geometric multiplicity for these eigenvalues. Write down the possible
Jordan forms of A.

Comment: I need urgent help please.I have doubt in how many jordan forms are coming and for which cases?

Comment: Is it mere coincidence that this is verbatim the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411584/265466? The other user at least showed a little bit of his work.

Comment: Saying that you need the answer urgently is a good way to get your question closed, since it makes it appear that you’re in the midst of an exam or doing your homework at the last minute.